# Como puedo exportar 2 tablas de HTML a Excel

Tags: javascript, html, spring-mvc

Tengo dos tablas elaboradas en HTML pero necesito exportar las dos en una misma hoja de excel.

Encontre este código que si me pone las dos tablas en una misma hoja pero no me toma en cuenta el footer de las dos tablas y tampoco me toma 2 columnas de la segunda tabla, donde deberia de modificar para insertar el footer como se ve en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Código JS*

```
                           var tablesToExcel = (function () {
               var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
               , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets>'
               , templateend = '</x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head>'
               , body = '<body>'
               , tablevar = '<table>{table'
               , tablevarend = '}</table>'
               , bodyend = '</body></html>'
               , worksheet = '<x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>'
               , worksheetend = '</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet>'
               , worksheetvar = '{worksheet'
               , worksheetvarend = '}'
               , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
               , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
               , wstemplate = ''
               , tabletemplate = '';               

               return function (table, name, filename) {
                   var tables = table;               

                   for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; ++i) {
                       wstemplate += worksheet + worksheetvar + i + worksheetvarend + worksheetend;
                       tabletemplate += tablevar + i + tablevarend;
                   }               

                   var allTemplate = template + wstemplate + templateend;
                   var allWorksheet = body + tabletemplate + bodyend;
                   var allOfIt = allTemplate + allWorksheet;               

                   var ctx = {};
                   for (var j = 0; j < tables.length; ++j) {
                       ctx['worksheet' + j] = name[j];
                   }               

                   for (var k = 0; k < tables.length; ++k) {
                       var exceltable;
                       if (!tables[k].nodeType) exceltable = document.getElementById(tables[k]);
                       ctx['table' + k] = exceltable.innerHTML;
                   }               

                   //document.getElementById("dlink").href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
                   //document.getElementById("dlink").download = filename;
                   //document.getElementById("dlink").click();               

                   window.location.href = uri + base64(format(allOfIt, ctx));               

               }
           })();
```

*JSP*

```
                               <thead>
                    <tr class="header-table">
                           <th>Actividades  </th>
                           <th>Duración en horas</th>
                           <th>Tipo de recurso</th>
                           <th>% asignado</th>
                           <th>Duración en semanas</th>
                           <th>Costo por hora</th>                                     
                           <th>Costo de resursos</th>
                           <th>Índice de riesgo</th>
                           <th>Bono de eficiencia</th>
                           <th>Costo total</th>
                           <th>Margen</th>
                           <th>Precio</th>
                           <th>Comisión de venta</th>
                           <th>Precio de venta</th>
                           <th>Precio promedio por hora</th>                
                                   </tr>                       
                               </thead>
                               <tbody >                   
                                   <c:forEach var="detalle" items="${model.detalles}">  
                                       <tr >
                                           <td>${detalle.actividad.nombreActividad}</td>
                                           <td>${detalle.duracionHoras}</td>
                                           <td>${detalle.recurso.nombreRecurso}</td>
                                           <td>${detalle.porcientoAsignado}%</td>
                                           <td>${detalle.duracionSemanas}</td>
                                           <td>${detalle.costoHora}</td>
                                           <td class="costoRecurso">${detalle.costoRecursos}</td>
                                           <td class="indiceRiesgo">${detalle.indiceRiesgo}</td>
                                           <td class="bonoEficiencia">${detalle.bonoDeEficiencia}</td>
                                           <td class="costoTotal">$${detalle.costoTotal}</td>
                                           <td class="margen">${detalle.margen}</td>
                                           <td class="precio">${detalle.precio}</td>
                                           <td class="comisionVenta">${detalle.comisionVentas}</td>
                                           <td class="precioVenta">${detalle.precioVenta}</td>
                                           <td class="precioPromedioVenta">${detalle.precioPromedioHora}</td>  

                                       </tr>
                                   </c:forEach>  
                               </tbody>
                               <tfoot>
                       <tr class="footer-table ">
                          <td  style="padding:0px;"> TOTAL </td>
                          <td  style="padding:0px;" class="totalDuracionHoras form-total" type="text">${model.proyecto.totalDuracionHoras }
                          </td>
                          <td  style="padding:0px;"> </td>
                          <td  style="padding:0px;"> </td>
                          <td  style="padding:0px;"> TOTAL </td>
                          <td  style="padding:0px;"> </td>
                          <td  style="padding:0px;" class="totalCostoRecurso form-total" type="text">${model.proyecto.totalCostoRecursos}
                          </td>
                          <td  style="padding:0px;" class="totalIndiceRiesgo form-total" type="text">${model.proyecto.totalIndiceRiesgo }
                          </td>
                          <td  style="padding:0px;" class="totalBonoEficiencia form-total" type="text">${model.proyecto.totalBonoEficiencia }
                          </td>
                          <td  style="padding:0px;" class="totalCostoTotal form-total" type="text">${model.proyecto.totalCostoTotal}
                          </td>
                          <td  style="padding:0px;" class="totalMargen form-total" type="text">${model.proyecto.totalMargen}
                          </td>
                          <td  style="padding:0px;" class="totalPrecio form-total" type="text"> ${model.proyecto.totalPrecio}
                          </td>
                          <td  style="padding:0px;" class="totalComisionVenta form-total" type="text">${model.proyecto.totalComisionVenta}
                         </td>
                         <td  style="padding:0px; color: red;" readonly="true"  class="totalPrecioVenta form-total" type="text"> ${model.proyecto.totalPrecioVenta}
                         </td>
                         <td   style="padding:0px; color: red;" readonly="true"  class="totalPrecioPromedio form-total" type="text">${model.proyecto.totalPrecioPromedio}
                         </td> 
                       </tr>
                   </tfoot>

               </table>
               </div><br><br>

           <!--   ========================================================== -->
               <div style="width:50%;" class="row">
               <table id="extras" class="table table-bordered table" >
                    <thead>
                       <tr class="header-table">
                           <th>Descripción  </th>
                           <th>Mensual</th>
                           <th>Anual</th>
                       </tr>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>
                   <tr>
                   <td>Soporte y mantenimiento de aplicación</td>
                   <td>
                           <form:input style="background:white;" readonly="true"   class=" montoMensualMantenimiento form-control input-table" path="montoMensualMantenimiento" type="text"/>               

                   </td>
                   <td>
                           <form:input style="background:white;" readonly="true" class=" montoAnualMantenimiento form-control input-table" path="montoAnualMantenimiento" type="text"/>

                   </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                   <td>Costos de infraestructura mensual</td>
                   <td>
                           <form:input style="background:white;" readonly="true"  class=" montoMensualInfraestructura form-control input-table" path="montoMensualInfraestructura" type="text"/>

                   </td>
                   <td>
                           <form:input style="background:white;" readonly="true"   class=" montoAnualInfraestructura form-control input-table" path="montoAnualInfraestructura" type="text"/>

                   </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                   <td>Precio total del proyecto</td>
                   <td>
                   <form:input style="background:white;" readonly="true" id="montoProyecto"  class=" montoProyecto form-control input-table" path="montoProyecto" type="text"/>
                   </td>
                   <td></td>
                   </tr>
                   </tbody>
                   <tfoot>
                       <tr class="footer-table form-total">
                          <td  style="padding:0px;"> TOTAL </td>
                         <td  style="padding:0px;">
                            <form:input readonly="true"  class="totalProyectoMensual form-control input-table" path="totalProyectoMensual" type="text"/>
                         </td>
                         <td  style="padding:0px;" readonly="true" id="totalProyectoAnual" class="totalProyectoAnual form-control input-table">
                            <form:input readonly="true" class="totalProyectoAnual form-control input-table" path="totalProyectoAnual" type="text"/>
                         </td>
                          </tr>
                   </tfoot>
               </table>
           </div>
                  <div class="pull-right">
              <a class="btn btn-info"  href="ListarProyecto" >Volver</a>
              </div>
                  <a id="dlink"  style="display:block;"></a>
               <input type="button" onclick="tablesToExcel(['table', 'extras'], ['first', 'second'], 'myfile.xls')" value="Export to Excel">
```

Comment: brother, este tipo de preguntas tienden a ser cerradas porque: 1. Carece de un intento de respuesta: código inexistente, 2. es demasiado amplio responder. Date una vuelta por https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que aprendas de qué va el sitio :D

Comment: Para poder exportar tablas creadas en HTML a excel existe un plugin llamado Datatables que básicamente añade funciones muy interesantes a tu tabla. Luego, tiene un plugin especifico que se encarga de exportar tablas a Excel: https://datatables.net/reference/button/excel Entonces, para exportar las dos, puedes jugar un poco con la api para simular que el botón con la que la exportas hace llamada a las 2 tablas que tienes para que te lo exporte todo en una misma hoja de excel. Aquí tienes un ejemplo : https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/4387/printing-exporting-multiple-datatables-at-once

Comment: Puedes usar este ejemplo, puedes agregar las tablas que quieras a diferentes worksheets https://jsfiddle.net/HectorCPR/7bcaro1j/10/